# How to create FQL query within query using userid from first query?

Tags: facebook-fql, fql.multiquery

I have an FQL query that is returning the list of people who have commented on a post:-

SELECT time, fromid, likes, post_id_cursor from comment where post_id = '331288023558058_592220760798115' ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 5000

What I'd like to do is to include another query within this query to return more details of the person leaving a comment

SELECT sex, first_name, middle_name, last_name, username, locale, profile_url, pic_square_with_logo FROM user WHERE uid = {fromid of person leaving comment}

Is it possible to combine the queries so that I get all the data in a single query? Any ideas how?

Thanks

Jonathan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use multiqueries

commentquery = "SELECT time, fromid, likes, post_id_cursor from comment where post_id = '331288023558058_592220760798115' ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 5000"

userquery = SELECT sex, first_name, middle_name, last_name, username, locale, profile_url, pic_square_with_logo FROM user WHERE uid = (SELECT fromid FROM #commentquery)

To user multiple FQL queries, you need to json_encode the queries in an array. for the /fql?q= parameter

So to specify:

```
$queries = [];
$queries['comments'] = "SELECT time, fromid... ";
$queries['users'] = "SELECT sex, ... WHERE uid IN (SELECT fromid FROM #comments)";

$fql = json_encode($queries);
// then using curl or whatever 
// (multiqueries don't work with PHP sdk's $facebook->api() i believe)
GET http://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=$fql
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, how do I json_encode the queries, I'm using PHP. It would be great if you could help me put it all together. Thanks

Comment: this is what I have so far $query = urlencode("SELECT time, fromid, likes, post_id_cursor from comment where post_id = '331288023558058_592220760798115' ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 5000");

$url = $baseurl.$query.$access_token;

$result = curl_load($url);

$commentids = json_decode($result);

Comment: My example is based on PHP. So easiest way is to put the two queries in an associative array and then do json_encode() on that array

Comment: Your URL that you curl GET should look in the end like this: https ://graph.facebook.com/fql?q={"comments":"SELECT+time,..","users":"SELECT+sex,..."}&access_token=AAAAAAA...

So maybe have the urlencode on the whole json string. and remember to add it to the "q" parameter

Answer (score 1):

Use a multi-query

`graph.facebook.com/fql?q={"query1":"SELECT time, fromid, likes, post_id_cursor from comment where post_id = '331288023558058_592220760798115' ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 5000","query2":"SELECT sex, first_name, middle_name, last_name, username, locale, profile_url, pic_square_with_logo FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT fromid FROM #query1)"}`

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/fql/

Answer (score 0):

You can probably find your answer here: [fql join; can i join two tables with FQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6553962/fql-join-can-i-join-two-tables-with-fql)

You want to join the two queries with a multiquery.  Hope that helps.